# Append value for an undefined variable in configuration file

Tags: shell, ansible

I have a variable value in set_fact, now i need to append that value in the config file. But this configuration file is coming from AMI, and there is no variable defined in the config file.

ex:
playbook.yml

```
- name: Get id
  set_fact:
     id: "{{ output.stdout }}"
```

file.config

```
ID =
```

Note: If I have ID = "{{ id }}" that would fix the problem, but I do not have that in the config file. I need to pass the ID value which is coming from playbook.yml

What I have tried
playbook.yml

```
- name: Get id
  set_fact:
     id: "{{ output.stdout }}"

- name: append value
  shell: "{{ item }}"
    - ID = "{{ id }}"
```

What I have got

file.config

```
ID =  
ID = 1233455
```

What I am expecting:
file.config

```
ID = 1233455
```

Note:
file.config
ID = <This line needs to be removed from the file or value should be appended here, there should not be any duplicates>

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell:

```yaml
- name: Add ID line in config file if id variable exists or remove it if not
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /path/to/file.config
    regexp: '^ID =.*$'
    line: "ID = {{ id | d('') }}"
    state: "{{ 'present' if id is defined else 'absent' }}"
```